# I am developing a website for hyperlocal logistics

Tags: google-maps

I intend to charge my customers with respect to the distance traveled by the item and the courier person.I have used google maps and want to specify the distance and the price the user needs to pay for our services beforehand.Can anybody tell me how can i find the distance between two addresses (not the radii distance) i.e. the distance by the road.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Distance Matrix API [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/start)